Integration of derivatives
I've recently finished my high school math finals and have come across this integral that gave me some issues:
$$\int f^2(x)f'(x)\,dx$$
(the exact function does not matter here) 
Initially, I solved it like this:
$$y=f(x)$$
$$\int f^2(x)f'(x)\,dx = \int y^2\frac{dy}{dx}\,dx $$
cancel dx's out:
$$=\int y^2dy = \frac{1}{3}y^3 + C$$
however, from what I've heard, you can't treat dy/dx as a fraction and canceling them out is not rigorous. In the exam I used IBP to solve this but I was wondering if there is a more detailed/right solution to this.
$$\int udv = uv - \int vdu$$
$$u = y => du =y'dx$$
$$dv = y *y' dx => v =\frac{1}{2}y^2$$
$$\int y^2y'dx=y*\frac{1}{2}y^2-\int \frac{1}{2}y^2y'dx$$
$$\frac{3}{2}\int y^2y'dx=\frac{1}{2}y^3$$
$$\int y^2y'dx=\frac{1}{3}y^3+C$$
PS I realize that there is a formula to solve this type of integral, but my question is not about how to solve the integral but about the "canceling" of the dx.

Does this address your concern?

One way to handle this integral is to just note that
$$
f^2(x)f'(x) = \left(\frac13f^3(x)+C\right)'
$$
so that
$$
\int f^2(x)f'(x)\,dx 
= \int \left(\frac13f^3(x)+C\right)' \, dx
= \frac13f^3(x)+C
$$
by the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Yes, I do think this is a simpler/more-robust way of thinking about it rather than the relabelling and worrying about "cancelling differentials"...

Here is a short response to

from what I've heard, you can't treat dy/dx as a fraction and
canceling them [the dx's] out is not rigorous
...
my question is not about how to solve the integral but about the
"canceling" of the dx.

That cancellation is not rigorous, but it's not hard to replace it by a rigorous argument. Mathematicians and physicists treat dx algebraically that way knowing their arguments can be formalized if necessary.
Searching on this site for dy/dx fraction provides links that may help.
